# Using the geoip maxmind.dat file with python

Tags: python, geolocation

Is there a python library to use the maxmind.dat file?
I have been using GeoLite2-City.mmdb with python library geoip2. However, it just can not read the .dat file.

> maxminddb.errors.InvalidDatabaseError: Error opening database file
>   (geoip_MAXMIND.dat). Is this a valid MaxMind DB file?

```
import geoip2.database
reader=geoip2.database.Reader('GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
 try:
      response = reader.city(ip_address)
      if response is not None:
      print response.city.name
      print response.subdivisions.most_specific.name
      print response.country.name
      print response.postal.code
 else:
      print "Not found\n"
 except:
      print "error"
```

Answer (score 1):

`geoip2` will only read the newer MaxMind DB format (`mmdb`). [pygeoip](https://pypi.org/project/pygeoip/) or [GeoIP](https://pypi.org/project/GeoIP/) will read the Legacy `dat` format.